# c++ - How can Eigen do dynamic matrix and vector multiplication?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm having trouble to do dynamic matrix and vector dot product and surprisingly, I didn't make it find any solution since `Eigen` is a prevalent library.

So the code is really simple:

```
int k = 3;
MatrixXd m;
m.resize(k, k);
ArrayXd a;
a.resize(k);
std::cout << "Dot product: " << m*a << std::endl;
```

I got error

> invalid operands to binary expression ('MatrixXd' (aka 'Matrix') and 'ArrayXd' (aka 'Array'))
>       std::cout << "Dot product: " << m*a << std::endl;

I'm confused if doing dynamic matrix and vector multiplication is feasible. Meanwhile, I found that there is `.dot()` method for vectors and matrices, so which one to use, `*` or `.dot()` for dot product?

Comment: There is a Matrix-Vector product, but not a Matrix-Array product. Just change the type of `a` to `VectorXd` to make your code work.

Comment: I recommend reading [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) and then [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseMatrixManipulation__chapter.html) to learn the basics of Eigen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have matrices, and not a mix of matrices and arrays. You need to convert `a` to an array (it's a view, no additional computational cost) with `.matrix()`.

Try:

```
std::cout << "Dot product: " << m*a.matrix() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the real quick answer! Just to make sure. So `Eigen` really don't support direct matrix vector multiplication, but I can achieve this my using `.matrix()` or `.vector()`?

Comment: It does, but you don't have a vector type (which would be `Vectorxf`IIRC), but a 1D array. You can use `dot` as well, but it should either between two matrices, or two arrays, not an array and a matrix.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `VectorXf` is a vector of `float`, which is incompatible to a `MatrixXd` (without casting). You'd need a `VectorXd` here.

Comment: @chtz oh, yes, of course, Vectorxd, not f. Thanks for the comment!